# How can I delete a focused property of an object with a van Laarhoven Lens?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lenses

With my simple lens implementation i can perform the usual modify, set, get and delete operations:

```js
// Lens type

const Lens = f => ({runLens: f, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Lens"});

const objLens = map => k =>
  Lens(f => o =>
    map(x => Object.assign({}, o, {[k]: x})) (f(o[k]))); // object lens

// Id type

const Id = x => ({runId: x, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Id"});
const idMap = f => tx => Id(f(tx.runId)); // functor

// Const type

const Const = x => ({runConst: x, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Const"});
const constMap = f => tx => Const(tx.runConst); // functor

// auxiliary function

const _const = x => y => x;

// MAIN

const o = {foo: "abc", bar: 123};

const get = objLens(constMap) ("foo").runLens(x => Const(x)) (o),
  set = objLens(idMap) ("bat").runLens(_const(Id(true))) (o),
  mod = objLens(idMap) ("foo").runLens(s => Id(s.toUpperCase())) (o),
  del = objLens(idMap) ("foo").runLens(_const(Id(null))) (o); //*

console.log("get", get.runConst);
console.log("set", set.runId);
console.log("mod", mod.runId);
console.log("del", del.runId);
```

However, `delete` is unsatisfying as I want to delete the whole property rather than merely replacing the value with nothing.

How can I achieve this?

*Please note that i usually would have used a proper `Option` type to indicate no values.

Comment: This is "simple"...? This barely resembles JavaScript to me. FP has always been a bit of a mental strain for me to decipher personally. Could you perhaps give a general explanation what you're trying to achieve with all this, and summarize what a "lens" is for us non-FPers?

Comment: Lenses/functional optics in general are an advanced topic, because they depend on the `Functor`/`Applicative` typeclasses. There are three crucial traits though: 1) You can compose them by defining compose/identity operators (and then e.g. set deeply nested properties without mutating the original object). 2) You can utilize the entire Functor/Applicative machinery not only `Id`/`Const` (i.e. they fit in the FP ecosystem) 3) By using the Applicative constraint you can combine them (e.g. set all nodes of a tree that contain an odd number, again without mutating the tree).

Comment: Thank you for humoring me. With that explanation, it's a little easier to understand how this code can be useful now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```js
// type Lens a b = forall f. Functor f => (b -> f b) -> a -> f a

// newtype Const b a = Const { getConst :: b } deriving Functor
const Const = getConst => ({ getConst, map: _ => Const(getConst) });

// newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a } deriving Functor
const Identity = runIdentity => ({ runIdentity, map: f => Identity(f(runIdentity)) });

// remove :: String -> Object -> Object
const remove = key => ({ [key]: _, ...rest }) => rest;

// prop :: String -> Lens Object (Maybe Value)
const prop = key => fun => obj =>
    fun(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? { fromJust: obj[key] } : null)
        .map(data => Object.assign(remove(key)(obj), data && { [key]: data.fromJust }));

// get :: Lens a b -> a -> b
const get = lens => data => lens(Const)(data).getConst;

// modify :: Lens a b -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
const modify = lens => fun => data => lens(x => Identity(fun(x)))(data).runIdentity;

// set :: Lens a b -> b -> a -> a
const set = lens => value => modify(lens)(_ => value);

// del :: Lens a (Maybe b) -> a -> a
const del = lens => set(lens)(null);

// foo :: Lens Object (Maybe Value)
const foo = prop("foo");

console.log(get(foo)({ foo: 10, bar: 20 })); // { fromJust: 10 }
console.log(del(foo)({ foo: 10, bar: 20 })); // { bar: 20 }
```

As seen, the type signature of a property lens like `foo` is `Lens Object (Maybe Value)`. This makes sense because if you try `get(foo)({ bar: 20 })` you should get nothing. The `del` function works on any lens which focuses on a maybe value, and sets its value to nothing (i.e. `null`).

Credit goes to Bergi for [showing me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616733/how-can-i-delete-a-focused-property-of-an-object-with-a-van-laarhoven-lens#comment99863586_56642887) that it's possible to pattern match on computed properties.

Comment: `const setMaybe /* String -> Object -> Maybe a -> Object */ = (prop) => ({[prop]: val, ...rest}) => fromMaybe(val => Object.assign(rest, {[prop]: val}))(rest)`?

Comment: @AaditMShah Yes, `maybe` instead of `fromMaybe`. I just thought the destructuring is much simpler than your `prop` function with the `remove` call...

Comment: _because if you try `get(foo)({bar: 20})` you should get nothing_ - Not sure if I want that as the default behavior. This indicates that you never know your object types. While this is sometimes true in dynamically typed languages you should normally know 'em.

Comment: Actually a implemented an object prism in a similar way to cover this "dynamic object case"

Comment: @bob If you know that a property will always exist then you can create a more specific lens for it (e.g. `const propExists = key => fun => obj => fun(obj[key]).map(val => Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: val }));`). However, now you can't delete that property because it would violate the requirement that it must always exist. On the other hand, if you have a property that can be deleted (i.e. which may or may not exist) then you necessarily have to check whether it exists and if it doesn't then you still have to return something. Hence, you wrap the property in a `Maybe`.

Comment: Another follow-up question has arisen: Considering the lens type `type Lens s t a b = forall f . Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`, doesn't the function `s -> f t` that takes an `s`-box and gives back a `t`-box in a functorial context witnesses that the outer type may change, i.e. the object type may change and this can be caused by a deleted property as well. So when I have a `Foo` object instance and delete a property and as a result it equals a `Bar` object instance isn't this totally valid?

Comment: Sure, lenses support polymorphic update. Hence, if you want to delete a property that always exists then you can use the lens `const propDel = key => fun => obj => fun(obj[key]).map(data => Object.assign(remove(key)(obj), data && { [key]: data.fromJust }));`. Similarly, if you want to add a property that may or may not exist you can use the lens `const propAssign = key => fun => obj => fun(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? { fromJust: obj[key] } : null).map(val => Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: val }));`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to define a special type that denotes deletion:

```js
const Lens = f => ({runLens: f, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Lens"});

const objLens = map => k =>
  Lens(f => o => map(x => {
    if (x[Symbol.toStringTag] === "Deleter") {
      const p = Object.assign({}, o);
      delete p[k];
      return p;
    }

    else
      return Object.assign({}, o, {[k]: x});
    }) (f(o[k])));

const Id = x => ({runId: x, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Id"});
const idMap = f => tx => Id(f(tx.runId)); // functor

const _const = x => y => x;

// deletion type

const Deleter =
  ({get runDeleter() {return Deleter}, [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Deleter"});

// MAIN

const o = {foo: "abc", bar: 123};

const del = objLens(idMap) ("foo").runLens(_const(Id(Deleter))) (o);

console.log("del", del.runId);
```

However, `_const(Id(Deleter))` isn't particularly intuitive, but looks hackish. Hopefully there is a better approach.